# RegEx that works in Javascript won't do so in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I will try to make my question short yet understandable, I have a simple RegEx I use in javascript to check for characters that aren't alphanumeric (AKA Symbols). It would be "/[$-/:-?{-~!"^_`[]]/"

In javascript, doing

```
if(/[$-/:-?{-~!"^_`\[\]]/.test( string ))
```

just works, if any of those characters are in the string, it will give true, else, it will give false. I tried to do the same in PHP, the following way

```
if(preg_match('/[$-/:-?{-~!"^_`\[\]]/', $string ))
```

other regexes work when done this way, but this particular one simply will give false no matter what when ran in PHP.

Is there any reason to this? Am I doing something wrong? Does PHP comprehend regexes in a different way? What should I change to make it work?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: `/` is your delimiter, you need to escape it in that character class. Surprised that doesnt throw an issue in JS. Also `$-/` is not a `$`, `-`, or `/`, it is a range (36 - 47, http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif)

Comment: @chris85 I assume that is because javascript regexes aren't strings and so it sees the `/` as part of an open character class. I'm surprised too though.

Comment: However, OP, instead of listing a bunch of characters you don't want, it is usually better to create a pattern of characters you do want. The list you provided isn't a complete list of all symbol characters by several thousand. Different keyboard layouts have characters that you don't have or see. You would be better off using a negated character class like `/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/` that means match anything that is not a letter or number. The `^` at the start of the class means *NOT* these characters.

Comment: Since php uses PCRE, you will get a pattern error using delimiter `/` as seen here https://regex101.com/r/3ILGgE/1

Comment: Issue corrected, thanks everyone. I will keep the negation method in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since php uses PCRE, you will get a pattern error using delimiter / as seen here http://regex101.com/r/3ILGgE/1

So, it should be escaped correctly.

Using `/` as the delimiter, the string is

```
'/[$-\/:-?{-~!"^_`\[\]]/'
```

Using `~` as the delimiter, the string is

```
'~[$-/:-?{-\~!"^_`\[\]]~'
```

Also, be aware you have a couple of range's in the class  `$-/` and `:-?` and `{-~`
that will include the characters between the from/to range characters as well
and *does not* include the range character `-` itself as it is an operator.